# If an n x n matix A is not invertible, then is 0 an eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that if $0$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$, then $A$ is not invertible, but is the opposite also true? If the matrix isn't invertible, is the eigenvalue always $0$?

Comment: Please always write formulas with MathJax. If you write the formulas like this, it can quickly become confusing and ambiguous, especially with more complex formulas.

Comment: If the matrix isn't invertible, $0$ is an eigenvalue, but there can be other eigenvalues. For example, $M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if $A$ is not invertible, then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Put another way, there must be a nonzero vector $y$ that satisfies $Ay=0$ hence $y$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Indeed, $A$ not invertible $\implies$ there are two distinct vectors $y_1,y_2$ such that $Ay_1=Ay_2$ $\implies$ $A(y_1-y_2)=0$ $\implies$ $y=y_1-y_2$ is a nonzero eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$ [since $Ay=0$ with $y =y_1-y_2 \not = 0$].

**Alternate proof:** Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be the $n$ row of $A$ [with $A$ a square matrix]. Then $A$ not invertible $\implies$ the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent $\implies$ there are scalars $c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_n$, at least one of the $c_i$s nonzero, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_ia_i = 0$ $\implies$ [letting $c$ be the following vector $c= [c_1,c_2, \ldots, c_n]^{\top}$] that $Ac = \sum_{i=1}^n c_ia_i = 0$ $\implies$ $c$ is an eigenvector of $A$, and is not $0$ [because one of the $c_i$s is not $0$] with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: More specifically, a nonzero vector $y$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is not invertible, then $\det(A) = 0$.

One might find the eigenvalues of $A$ by finding the roots of its characteristic polynomial:

$$\det(A-\lambda I) = 0.$$

And since $\det(A) = 0$, $\lambda = 0$ is a root and so is an eigenvalue.

Comment: you mean that det$\left(A\right)$ = det$\left(A- 0 \cdot I\right)$ = $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

One way to think about it is if a square matrix is not invertible, it is linearly dependent. If the columns of a matrix are linearly dependent, there exists a linear combinations of the columns that sums to the $0$ vector.

$A \vec{b} = \vec0$

In this situation A is acting like a scalar multiple of $\vec{b}$. This is the definition of an eigenvalue. The factor it is scaling $\vec{b}$ by, $0$, is the eigenvalue.

$A\times0 = \vec0$

Thus, $0$ is an eigenvalue for all non-invertible square matrices.

Answer (score -1):

The condition of non-invertibility amounts to $\det(A)=0$ which in turn is equivalent to that the rank of $A$ is not maximal. But that means that you can find a non-zero column $X$ such that
$$
A\cdot X=0.
$$
Thinking of $X$ as a vector, the displayed formula says that $X$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$.